# How do I display grade letters?

Tags: c#

I have a program that is suppose to display the corresponding letter grade A,B,C,D,E. Instead is prints the numeric value. I classified it as a decimal because I did not know what you classify text under. How do I fix this?

```
private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal Score = 0 , Percent, Average = 0, Letter = 0, GrandTotal = 0;

    if (NameTextBox.Text != "" && ScoreTextBox.Text != "")
    {
        if (Score >= 0 && Score <= 150)
        {
            Score = decimal.Parse(ScoreTextBox.Text);
            Percent = Score / 150;
            if (Score >= 90)
                Letter = 'A';
            else if (Score >= 80 && Score < 90)
                Letter = 'B';
            else if (Score >= 70 && Score < 80)
                Letter = 'C';
            else if (Score >= 60 && Score < 70)
                Letter = 'D';
            else if (Score < 60)
                Letter = 'E';

            GrandTotal += 1;
            Average += Score; 

            PercentTextBox.Text = Percent.ToString("P");
            LetterGradeTextBox.Text = Letter.ToString();
            GrandTotalTextBox.Text = Percent.ToString();
            AverageTextBox.Text = Average.ToString("P");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Score must be a positive number between 0 - 150");
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Name and a Score between 0 - 150 are required");
}
```

Comment: `&& Score < 90` -- You already know this, from the `if` statement above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `Letter` to be a `string`, instead of a `decimal`:

```
string Letter = "";
```

then set your textboxes to the letter:

```
LetterGradeTextBox.Text = Letter;
```

Also, you'll need to change setting `Letter` to a `string` (double quotes):

```
 Letter = "A";
```

Answer (score 0):

**You must define Letter as a Text character**

```
string Letter="";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a character to a decimal: Letter = 'A'/'B'.../'E'

So, the Ascii value of 'A'/'B'.../'E' is assigning to Letter.

If you assign 'A' then Letter = 65 is assigned.

So, declare Letter as a string, and then assign value.